# How to calculate $ \lim_{z\to0} \frac{(z\overline{z})^{2}}{z^{2}} $?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex variable and $\overline{z}$ denotes complex conjugate what is the value of 
$$
\lim_{z\to0} \dfrac{(z\overline{z})^{2}}{z^{2}}?
$$

I tried to solve using $z=x+iy$; using $\lim_{x\to 0}$ & $\lim_{y\to0}$ , i never solved problem with two entity.

Comment: PLEASE do not change your question in a fundamental different way after 
 you post it.

Comment: The fraction is equal to $\bar{z}^2$.

Comment: I think you mean that $\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate, not $z\bar z$.

Answer (score 2):

Polars reveal here.  Setting

$z = re^{i\theta} \tag 1$

for $z \ne 0$, we have

$\bar z = re^{-i\theta}, \tag 2$

whence

$\dfrac{\bar z^2}{z^2} = \dfrac{r^2 e^{-2i\theta}}{r^2 e^{2i\theta}} = e^{-4i\theta}; \tag 3$

since

$\vert z \vert = r, \tag 4$

we see that $z \to 0$ if and only if $r \to 0$; but according to (3), $\bar z^2 / z^2$ takes on many different, ray-dependent values according to the angle $\theta$ associated with each half-line emanating from the origin; hence the limit as $z \to 0$ does not exist.

Comment: Gorgeous answer!

Answer (score 0):

Simply the limit doesn't exist. You can think it as the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left(\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2+2ixy}\right)^2$$
For example along the line $x=y$ the limit is $-1$.
Along the line $X=0$ is $1$

Comment: $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$ & $(z)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy$

Comment: I know...
$$
\lim_{z\to0} \frac{(\overline{z})^{2}}{z^{2}}=\lim_{z\to 0}(\dfrac{z\bar{z}}{z^2})^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is only one entity here ($z$), not two.

If $z$ is real (and $z\neq0$), then $\frac{\overline z^2}{z^2}=1$ and if $z=\lambda(1+i)$, with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, then $\frac{\overline z^2}{z^2}=-1$. Therefore, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In polar,  $z=re^{i\theta}$ so $\frac {\bar z^2}{z^2}=\frac {r^2e^{-2i\theta}}{r^2e^{2i\theta}}=e^{-4i\theta}$.Since $\theta $ can take any value as $z \to 
 0$ and $e^{-4i\theta}$ moves around the unit circle centered at $0$ there is no limit. ..